# Reset array keys back to [0] [1] [2]

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any function or something to reset the keys of an array?

I have this array:

```
Array ( [4] => 8 [6] => 3 [7] => 2 [8] => 7 )
```

I need it to be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 [3] => 7 )
```

I've tried some `for` cycles and stuff like that to replace the keys but there's probably something out there that does this automatically and instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can just use

```
$yourarray = Array ( [4] => 8 [6] => 3 [7] => 2 [8] => 7 );
$desired_array = array_values($yourarray);
```